# Adding autocomplete dropdown field to flask application builder viewmodel

Tags: python, ajax, flask, flask-appbuilder

Using flask app builder, a ModelRestApi was registered and responds when browsed to. I would like to use this API to populate an AjaxSelectField, which uses the Select2AJAXWidget to add autocomplete and search functionality.

I created a model with a `__bind_key__` that points to the external data. [The Select2AJAXWidget widget seems to be using the WTForm AjaxSelect field](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/examples/related_fields/app/views.py). However no data is populated by the widget, even if I pass it the API url.

How can I verify that the data from the API is effectively bieng populated into the widget?

[image: Trying to get some data in the widget!]